# Magento 2.3.0 calendar selection issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.6, magento2.3.0

I have a store with Italian Language with Magento 2.3.0. In that store, I have created a calendar and I am facing some issue while selecting the date from the calendar.

My Date Format is dd/MM/yy. My expected out is "12 March 2019". But I am always getting this 12/03/2019.

```
    $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
    $escapedDateFormat = preg_replace('/[^MmDdYy\/\.\-]/', '', $this->getDateFormat());
    $this->dateElement->setData([
        'extra_params' => $this->isRequired() ? 'data-validate="{required:true}"' : '',
        'name' => 'expired_date',
        'id' => 'expired_date',
        'class' => $this->getHtmlClass().'required-entry',
        'value' => $this->getRequiredDate(),
        'date_format' => $this->getDateFormatVals(),
        'image' => $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Theme::calendar.png'),
        'change_month' => 'true',
        'change_year' => 'true',
        'show_on' => 'both'
    ]);
```

[image: Date picker]

Now my issue is language(locale is working fine). But when I am selecting the date instead of 31/March/2019 Its showing 31/03/2019 . Could you please tell what is the exact issue .

Answer (score 0):

Its a default Magento bug :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11156

To fix this issue you need to update the file :

> vendor\magento\framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\DateTime.php

Change line **46** as below

from :

```
$dateTime = $this->_localeDate->date($value, null, false);
```

To :

```
$dateTime = $this->_localeDate->date($value, null, false, false);
```

Comment: still same issue. Still coming as 20/03/2019